# ZF2 initializers and TranslatorAwareInterface

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I think this is a simple question.

ZF2's `ServiceManager` can automatically inject dependencies if certain interfaces are implemented in a class, ie. `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` or `EventManagerAwareInterface`.

My question is: why does it not inject the translator when I'm implementing `TranslatorAwareInterface`?

Comment: How are you instantiating the class?

Comment: By calling $serviceman->get('Class'), which will call a factory for this class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the ZF2 `ServiceManager` config has default `initializers` for services implementing a `ServiceManagerAwareInterface` or a `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`.

You can find the `ServiceManagerAwareInitializer` and `ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer` in the [`__construct` method of the `ServiceManagerConfig`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php#L93).

To achieve this for your own interfaces you will have to register your own `initializer`. Here an example on how you can do this for a translator:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        //...
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        //...
        'translator' => 'My\Factory\TranslatorFactory'
    ),
    'initializers' => array(
        // Inject translator into TranslatorAwareInterface
        'translator' => function($service, ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
            if ($service instanceof TranslatorAwareInterface) {
                $translator = $serviceLocator->get('translator');
                $service->setTranslator($translator);
            }
        }
    )
)
```

You have to make sure you registered your translator as `translator` in the `serviceManager` to make this work. I created it with a `My\Factory\TranslatorFactory`.

Read more on `initializers` in the [ZF2 documentation for the `ServiceManager`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html).

Be aware that for every service you create the `initializer` will check whether it needs to inject your dependency.

Comment: I think zf2 had this initializer by default and for some reason they removed it: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack-td4661094.html